# Laravel BadMethodCallException

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have been loosely following this tutorial (http://jasonlewis.me/article/laravel-using-forms-and-the-validator) and switching between this and the Laravel docs to try and get some form of validation on my registration form. I am using Laravel 4.1 and have moved some of the routes to a controller.

This is my route code for the signup page

```
Route::resource('signup', 'Signup');
```

My View code...

```
{{ Form::open(array('signup', 'post')) }}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-10 large-centered columns @if($errors->has()) error @endif">
            {{ Form::label('name', 'Name') . Form::text('name') }}
            @if($errors->has())
                <small class="error">{{ $errors->first('name') }}</small>
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-10 large-centered columns @if($errors->has()) error @endif">
            {{ Form::label('email', 'Email Address') . Form::email('email') }}
            @if($errors->has())
                <small class="error">{{ $errors->first('email') }}</small>
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-10 large-centered columns">
            {{ Form::submit('Submit', array('class' => 'success button')) }}
        </div>
    </div>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

My controller code...

```
public function store()
{
    //
    $rules = array(
        'name' => array('required', 'users,name'),
        'email' => array('required', 'email', 'unique:users,email')
    );

    $validation = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    if ($validation->fails())
    {
        // Validation has failed.
        return Redirect::to('signup')->withInput()->withErrors($validation);
    }
}
```

Now for the problem... If I leave all the fields blank, it comes up with errors telling me nothing has been entered which is fine and same for when I enter an email, but nothing else. But when I enter a name it tells me that Method [validateUsers,name] does not exist.

I have tried changing the array to just name and signup,name but it still comes up with the error changing the method respectively. I would like to know what am I doing wrong and how can I fix this when the fields have been filled in?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with `users,name` in `'name' => array('required', 'users,name'),`?

Comment: I wasn't entirely sure, I just followed the guys tutorial. I have removed that part and now everything is working. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to say `unique` in name too:

```
$rules = array(
    'name' => array('required', 'unique:users,name'),
    'email' => array('required', 'email', 'unique:users,email')
);
```

But you really want to make name an unique column? You might encounter problems with this... So you could just go with:

```
$rules = array(
    'name' => array('required'),
    'email' => array('required', 'email', 'unique:users,email')
);
```